# Siblings Want To Charge Me Rent To Stay In Our Inherited Property For One Year

Tags: united-states

My 3 siblings and I inherited our parents house in 2011. The home has no mortgage. I have paid my 1/4 of the taxes each year since 2012 have never missed a payment. I have also paid my 1/4 of the insurance and have never missed a payment. Renovations have be done in the home. I contributed my 1\4 each time. One sibling has never contributed to the insurance. another sibling was given money to make repairs, but never provided proper receipts. Now that I need to move into the home for one year in order to recover from loss of income since the COVID-19 shut down my job, my siblings want to charge me 10,000.00 for one year of rent. Can they legally charge me rent?

Comment: Who actually is on the title?

Answer (score 3):

If it is joint title then all parties must agree. If one disagrees no one can enter.

[https://www.investopedia.com/articles/mortgages-real-estate/08/title-ownership-property.asp#:~:text=Joint%20tenancy%20occurs%20when%20two,tenancy%20at%20the%20same%20time](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/mortgages-real-estate/08/title-ownership-property.asp#:%7E:text=Joint%20tenancy%20occurs%20when%20two,tenancy%20at%20the%20same%20time).

Joint Tenancy
Joint tenancy occurs when two or more people hold title to real estate jointly, with equal rights to enjoy the property during their lives. If one of the partners dies, their rights of ownership pass to the surviving tenant(s). Tenants can enter into a joint tenancy at the same time. This usually occurs through a deed

Comment: What do you mean by "enter"? If one co-owner says that another co-owner cannot enjoy full use of the property, that does not deprive the other co-owner's right to full use of the property.

Comment: It depends on the las

Comment: The las? The law? The last?